# How to measure the second derivatives of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, derivative

I am at very first step in MATLAB programming and when I read an article about image processing, I see in most of them it has written that the first and/or second derivatives should be estimated.

How I can measure the second derivatives (Gxx,Gxy,Gyy) over the gradient?

Comment: Flag being said, you should probably type "introduction to image processing" or something like that into google.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: thanks Mad Physicist I found it right now.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of applying successive differences, you could apply the second derivative kernel in each dimension:

```
Gx = [1 -2 1]; Gy = Gx'; %' y kernel is column vector
img = double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
Dxx = conv2(img,Gx,'same');
Dyy = conv2(img,Gy,'same');
```

If you were after a non-directional second derivative, you should use the Laplacian. A common kernel is:

```
L = [0  1  0;
     1 -4  1;
     0  1  0;] % fspecial('laplacian',alpha=0)
D2 = conv2(img,L,'same');
```

As in the comment above, you can use `fspecial` to get variations on the kernel that capture diagonal differences via the `alpha` parameter.  Or you can use `del2`:

```
D2 = del2(img);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into imgradient from the Image Processing Toolbox. Two applications of that should give you what you want.

Something like this:

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
[Gx,Gy] = imgradientxy(im);
[Gxx,Gxy] = imgradientxy(Gx);
[Gyy,Gyx] = imgradientxy(Gy);
```

This uses a Sobel filter to compute derivatives. You can also use Prewitt, central differences or intermediate differences by passing this as a string to imgradientxy.

Hope that helps.